# If odds of an event is $80\%$, how many events needed until you get $n$ consecutive events?

Tags: probability, expectation

Odds of hitting a home run is $80\%$.

You get $1$ at-bat per day.

How long can you expect it will it take to finally get a streak of $30$ home runs?

Does this relate to geometric probability?

Comment: If each bat is independent of the other, then getting a streak of 30 home-runs has a probability of .8^30, and the number of attempts at bat you've had before that is irrelevant.

Comment: @JonathanHebert: OP is asking about the expectancy, not the probability.

Comment: Ok, so P(30 HR's) = .8^30    --> E(x) = 1/p     -->  so E(x) = $\frac{1}{.8^{30}}$ =  807 days   ??

Comment: Call $t_n$ the mean time to get a streak of $n$ homeruns, then $t_1=1$ and, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$t_{n+1}=t_n+1+(1-p)t_{n+1},$$ with $p=.8$. Thus, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$t_n=\frac1{p^n}\frac{p(2-p)}{1-p}-\frac1{1-p}.$$ This proof does not require Mathematica. The result is not $1/p^n$. For instance, $$t_{30}\approx3872.$$

Comment: A new twist on the site: OP posts question, OP posts wrong answer to own question, OP accepts wrong answer. Convenient.

Comment: Can you explain (or tell me what topic to research) to understand your method?

Comment: Did, is this the same answer as what you formulated?   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218810/pbowling-a-strike-70-expected-number-of-trials-until-a-perfect-game-10-s

Answer (score -3, accepted):

$P(30 HRs) = .8^{30} $

$E(x) = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{.8^{30}} = 807 days $

Comment: Did you read @Did's comment, or has Math.SE become like the op-ed page of the Washington Post?

Comment: What is wrong with this approach?   Can't you think of the 30 days as 1 chunked event?